# Repeater itemboungf is repeating more than required?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, event-handling

The two events are

```
 protected void btnuplaod_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string filepath = Server.MapPath(@"~/Admin/temp/");
    Session["Image"] = Request.Files;
    HttpFileCollection uploadedFiles = (HttpFileCollection)Session["Image"];
    lblerror.Text = string.Empty;

    for (int i = 0; i < uploadedFiles.Count; i++)
    {
        HttpPostedFile userPostedFile = uploadedFiles[i];

        try
        {
            if (userPostedFile.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                lblerror.Text += "<u>File #" + (i + 1) + "</u><br>";
                lblerror.Text += "File Content Type: " + userPostedFile.ContentType + "<br>";
                lblerror.Text += "File Size: " + userPostedFile.ContentLength + "kb<br>";
                lblerror.Text += "File Name: " + userPostedFile.FileName + "<br>";
                userPostedFile.SaveAs(filepath + Path.GetFileName(userPostedFile.FileName));
                lblerror.Text += "Location where saved: " + filepath + "\\" + Path.GetFileName(userPostedFile.FileName) + "<p>";

            }
            repimages.DataSource = filepath;
            Session["repimage"] = userPostedFile.FileName;
            repimages.DataBind();
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            lblerror.Text += "Error: <br>" + Ex.Message;
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
 protected void repimages_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        string filepath = Server.MapPath(@"~/Admin/temp/");
        lblerror.Text = string.Empty;
            Image img = e.Item.FindControl("postedimage") as Image;
            img.ImageUrl = filepath + Session["repimage"];
    }
```

repimages_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e) event is repeating 48 times for a single image

Answer (score 0):

**repimages_ItemDataBound** is invoked when item in your repeater is bound from your datasource. How can it be invoked with a button click?

Comment: actually on button click event i am storing multiple image in a folder and i want them to get display to user on that button click that's why  i was thinking about this alternative is there is any another method to do this. do this repeater can be bound with that folder

Comment: you have to bind repeater once again to reflect updates in data. repimages_ItemDataBound handler has nothing related to it, I think.

Answer (score 0):

you have to bind repImages on button click which will internally call repImages_ItemDataBound provided in your aspx you have this OnItemDataBound="repImages_ItemDataBound"

Comment: yes exacly what i did now but now the repeater is repeating 50  times can u please chec i am posting my code

Comment: what are you trying to do? your databind is in for loop so it will bind 50 times and last one will overwrite previos..